# How fix the permissions for a mac app

Tags: applications, permission

I opened my `Frank DeLoupe.app` application and it asked for permissions. A window popup that I almost always click allow. This time I clicked deny, and now the color picker is not working.

How can I give this app permission?

I've tried adding the app to the accessibility whitelist (preferences > Security and privacy). That made no difference.

(The problem is that when I open this color picker, it doesn't "see" the screen I am on)